# why is not reading the variable in pl sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please can you guide me on where im wrong. What i want to achieve is if the database name is either DEV or QA, run the dir creation.  It should skip the deployment on other envs like PRD_DEV, PRD_QA etc

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
lv_create_dir_sql varchar2(400) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY REFRESH as ''/mnt/refresh'';'
lc_s_db_name    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'DEV';
lc_p_db_name    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'QA';

begin

    select name into lv_db_name from v$database;
 begin
    
     if (lv_db_name <> lc_s_db_name) or
        (lv_db_name <> lc_p_db_name) then
        
        execute immediate lv_create_dir_sql;
    end if;
 end;
/
```

Comment: You have a second `begin` there; that's unnecessary (and you don't have a corresponding second `end` either).

Comment: I would seriously question the premise.  Creation of objects (tables, directories, etc) should be done as part of the design implementation, not done on the fly.  What _business_ problem is this supposed to address?

Comment: EdStevens - we use Flway to orchestrate the deployment in all envs. This is to simply avoid creating dir in envs where its not needed as part of user requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things wrong in the code

- You are using 2 `begin`, but only one `end`. The second `begin` is not needed.
- If you are creating a directory, you will need to grant privileges over that directory to someone I guess
- The `;` in the statement that creates the directory must be outside.
- It is not clear whether you want or not to create the directory when the database is either DEV or QA. If you want use `in` , if not use `not in`
- replace `user1` and `user2` for the users you want to grant privileges over.

So

```
set serveroutput on
declare
lv_create_dir_sql varchar2(400) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY REFRESH as ''/mnt/refresh'' ';
lv_create_dir_grt varchar2(400) := 'grant read,write on directory REFRESH to user1, user2 '  ;
lc_s_db_name      varchar2(30)  := 'DEV';
lc_p_db_name      varchar2(30)  := 'QA';
begin
    select name into lv_db_name from v$database;
    if lv_db_name in ( lc_s_db_name , lc_p_db_name ) -- if you want to create the directory when the db is any of the two. If not, use not in
    then
         execute immediate lv_create_dir_sql;
         execute immediate lv_create_dir_grt;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: appreciate it. it works now. thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared variable lv_db_name anywhere.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
lv_create_dir_sql varchar2(400) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY REFRESH as ''/mnt/refresh'';'
lc_s_db_name    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'DEV';
lc_p_db_name    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'QA';
lv_db_name      VARCHAR2(100);
begin

    select name into lv_db_name from v$database;
 begin
    
     if (lv_db_name <> lc_s_db_name) or
        (lv_db_name <> lc_p_db_name) then
        
        execute immediate lv_create_dir_sql;
    end if;
 end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
(lv_db_name <> lc_s_db_name)
or (lv_db_name <> lc_p_db_name)
```

which means it will always create the directory, because 'DEV' <> 'QA'!

You should say

```
(lv_db_name = lc_s_db_name)
or (lv_db_name = lc_p_db_name)
```

or more smoothly:

```
lv_db_name in (lc_s_db_name, lc_p_db_name)
```